# Format number from Zero to Six decimal points in PHP

Tags: php, number-formatting

I want to display numbers up to 6 decimal points.

Like this:

```
99.0000001 -> 99
99.000001  -> 99.000001
99.00001   -> 99.00001
99.0001    -> 99.0001
99.001     -> 99.001
99.01      -> 99.01
99.10      -> 99.10
99.00      -> 99
```

What would be an elegant way to do this in PHP?

Comment: number_format()

Comment: Simple number_format() doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Use [round()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php), with precision 6

```
<?php
echo round(99.0000001, 6).PHP_EOL;
echo round(99.000001, 6).PHP_EOL;
echo round(99.00001, 6).PHP_EOL;
echo round(99.0001, 6).PHP_EOL;
echo round(99.001, 6).PHP_EOL;
echo round(99.01, 6).PHP_EOL;
echo round(99.10, 6).PHP_EOL;
echo round(99.00, 6).PHP_EOL;
```

https://3v4l.org/5lWCa

**Result:**

```
99
99.000001
99.00001
99.0001
99.001
99.01
99.1
99
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.
Removal of addition digits after 6th decimal digit.

```
$z = 99.0000011;  
$y = floor($z * 1000000) / 1000000;
```

Then to calculate amount of digits after decimal remaining.

```
$str = "$y";
$dcount = strlen(substr(strrchr($str, "."), 1));
```

Now we have to determine if the value should have decimals or not and if so , need to have 2 or more decimals.

```
$a = 0; 
If ($dcount == 1) {$a = $dcount+1;} 
else {$a = $dcount;} 
$x = number_format((float)$y, $a, '.', '');
```

$x would be the required result you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I had in mind. I was wondering if there was a better/more elegant way...